# Typescript: Import Class from another npm module

Tags: node.js, class, npm, typescript

I'm working on node.js with npm. I've written a TS library and I want to use it in another project by doing npm install.
I'm not sure what will should be the contents in my npm package:
should it be only .js, only .ts, or .js with additional declaration files (d.ts)?

Furthermore if I'm using the third option, what exactly am I writing in the definition file? how exactly am I using it?I'm not sure what's the connection between d.ts and the actual javascript.
I see a lot of different answers but most them didn't help me.

Thanks,
      Omer

Comment: If it were me, I would only output js file(s) in the published package, and provide the .d.ts via [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped). As for generating declaration files (.d.ts), you can use the --declaration of the tsc command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ship the JavaScript file, because TypeScript files in your NPM package won't be compiled - but you can additionally ship the .d.ts (or even the .ts file) to provide type information to your consumers.

This isn't a bad pattern to use for NuGet packages either - even though you can place the files into the target project.